# What is the JSCC.get ... init?

Tags: javascript

I want to build such a structure. Json data looked at Facebook.com. I face the following code in the output. **JSCC.get here .... init** how it works. Do not help me in this matter?

```
"onload"    :["JSCC.get('/j4e7daf70e8d78540345959110').init(HTML(\"\\u003cdiv ........
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to produce the output Json. Facebook has made with the js. I'm trying to learn what works JSCC.get function.

Comment: I went my json {"_content": {"html":"<form id=\"test\"></form>"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved!**

```
    .....
    JQuery Ajax Text Code
    .....

    eval(json.onload)

    var JSCC = {
       get : function(){},
       init: function(){}

    }

$.extend(JSCC);
```

Answer (score 2):

JSCC appears to be some Facebook-internal API. There doesn't seem to be anything published about it, which means that it's most likely proprietary, and can't be legally used by anyone except Facebook.